# PHP undefined offset from list()

Tags: php

```
list(,,,,,,,,,$user, $pass) = explode("\t", $line);
if(trim($user) == $_POST['username'] && trim($pass) == $_POST['password'] )
```

The message undefined offset 10 , The message undefined offset 9 . the 9 and the 10 is the $user and $pass. How do i fix the error? and does undefined offset means its not being declared or something? and theres alot of ,,,,,,,, is because theres value but i dont need it for this php

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`undefined offset` in this context means that you are expecting more parameters in your call to `list` than are in the array on the right hand of the equation.

You are expecting an array with a length of 11 but `explode("\t", $line)` is returning an array of less than 11 values.

You either need to ensure you have the right amount of tab separated values in `$line` or pad the output of `explode` using [`array_pad`](https://www.php.net/array-pad).

Below is an example of using [`array_pad`](https://www.php.net/array-pad) to make sure the array has a length of 11:

```
list(,,,,,,,,,$user, $pass) = array_pad(explode("\t", $line), 11, null);
```

If `$line` did not contain enough tab separated values then `$user` and `$pass` would take the value `null`.