# PHP Undefined offset Message when using "list" function

Tags: php, undefined, offset

I got this error on my website this morning when I click on post-ad

I have tried looking at the code but don't seem to find anything wrong

```
if (!function_exists('adforest_extarct_link')) {

    function adforest_extarct_link($string) {
        $arr = explode('|', $string);
        list($url, $title, $target, $rel) = $arr; /* This is line 148 */
        $rel = urldecode(adforest_themeGetExplode($rel, ':', '1'));
        $url = urldecode(adforest_themeGetExplode($url, ':', '1'));
        $title = urldecode(adforest_themeGetExplode($title, ':', '1'));
        $target = urldecode(adforest_themeGetExplode($target, ':', '1'));
        return array("url" => $url, "title" => $title, "target" => $target, "rel" => $rel);
    }
```

This is the error Message

> Undefined offset: 3 in /customers/7/6/1/corpersmarket.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/adforest/inc/theme_shortcodes/short_codes_functions.php on line 148

It actually has 3 lines of error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /customers/7/6/1/corpersmarket.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/adforest/inc/theme_shortcodes/short_codes_functions.php on line 148 
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /customers/7/6/1/corpersmarket.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/adforest/inc/theme_shortcodes/short_codes_functions.php on line 148 
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /customers/7/6/1/corpersmarket.com/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/adforest/inc/theme_shortcodes/short_codes_functions.php on line 148
```

Comment: looks like you are not passing proper parameter to adforest_extarct_link function, $string = "url|title|target|rel"

Comment: ok so I should add the rest code after $string? @sureshbambhaniya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP undefined offset from list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401788/php-undefined-offset-from-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question is broadly a duplicate of [PHP undefined offset from list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401788/php-undefined-offset-from-list)

However,

Your `list` expects at least 4 prameters -- but your `$arr` array only has 1. So the following three are empty. (remember arrays start at 0). So your `$string` does not contain a `|` character for the `explode` function to work as intended.

## [Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365392/optional-parameters-to-php-list-function):

Original:

```
    $arr = explode('|', $string);
    list($url, $title, $target, $rel) = $arr; /* This is line 148 */
```

Becomes:

```
    $arr = array_pad(explode('|', $string), 4, null);
    list($url, $title, $target, $rel) = $arr;
```

## What this does:

[Pads the array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) out to contain a minimum of 4 values; so that the `list` values will always be populated, even if they may still be empty.

Comment: That works thanks for the tutorial as I have learned something new today.

Comment: @Isaac that's great. If this works you can click the up arrow and the tick by the answer to mark it as the best answer. Thanks!